# Whats the way to find the greatest common divisor?

Tags: vb.net

how can find the greatest common divisor for 3 Textboxes values and make it apper in the forth Textbox ?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim d As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        b = Val(TextBox2.Text)
        c = Val(TextBox3.Text)
        d = Val(TextBox4.Text)

        -------------------------   Val(TextBox4.Text) = ----------------

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is math, not programming

Comment: See: [Greatest common divisor / Using Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set the highest minimum value for the greatest common denominator:

`Dim minimum As Integer
        If a <= b And a <= c 
            minimum = a
        Else If b <= a And a <= c
            minimum = b
        Else If c <= a And a <= b
            minimum = c
        End If`

Use a for loop and Mod equations like so:

`For i As Integer = minimum To 1 Step -1
            If a Mod i = 0 And b Mod i = 0 And c Mod i = 0
                Return i
            End If
 Next`

This will set the lowest number as variable minimum and count down until i has no remainders for a, b, and c, thus yielding the greatest common denominator.

Comment: It is `If a <= b And a <= c Then`. The same with the others `Else If`. Or `minimum = Math.Min(a, b) minimum = Math.Min(minimum, c)`

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that.